# this code get me all the contacts...I want only the contact which has phone number starts with 011

Tags: android

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
        startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {

      if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT)
      {         

        getContactInfo(intent);         
        System.out.println("HASPHONE NUMBER"+phoneNumber);
        // Your class variables now have the data, so do something with it. 
      }
    }//onActivityResult

    protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
    {

       Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {           
           String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

           String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))


               hasPhone = "true";
           else
               hasPhone = "false" ;

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
           {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
            {

                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            }
            phones.close();
           }

           // Find Email Addresses
           Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null, null);
           while (emails.moveToNext()) 
           {
            String emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
           }
           emails.close();

        Cursor address = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
                    null, null);
        while (address.moveToNext()) 
        { 
          // These are all private class variables, don't forget to create them.
             String poBox      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
             String street     = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
             String city       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
             String state      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
             String postalCode = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
             String country    = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
String  type   = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
        }  //address.moveToNext()   
      }  //while (cursor.moveToNext())        
       cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
    {

String number[];
       Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null); 
     number=new String[cursor.getCount()];
int numCount=0;

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {           
           String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

           String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))


               hasPhone = "true";
           else
               hasPhone = "false" ;

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
           {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
            {

                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
               if(phoneNumber.startsWith("011")) number[numCount++]=phoneNumber;  
            }
            phones.close();
           }

           // Find Email Addresses
           Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null, null);
           while (emails.moveToNext()) 
           {
            String emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
           }
           emails.close();

        Cursor address = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
                    null, null);
        while (address.moveToNext()) 
        { 
          // These are all private class variables, don't forget to create them.
             String poBox      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
             String street     = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
             String city       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
             String state      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
             String postalCode = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
             String country    = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
String  type   = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
        }  //address.moveToNext()   
      }  //while (cursor.moveToNext())        
       cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: there was nochange in the list..it shows all the contacts in phone

Comment: where you did you populate the list

Comment: I took  the list from phone contactlist

Comment: when taking list just match as i said.So you can ignore the contacts not having 011 at the beginning

Comment: i need a contactlist which should show only the number that starts with 011.